# faces not appear from some angles in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I create very simple models in Blender contains some faces with color materials then export them to Collada format and import into Three.js, the problem is some faces do not appear from some angles of view, i create this model from plane then exclude it to make modeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your faces are probably facing (hehe) the wrong way. Try inverting these faces in blender and then export again.

Or try making a double sided material that draws the material inside and outside, but the first option is more efficient.

[See this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RW3QNW5z5Tk)

Comment: thank you, is there a method to convert all faces or i have to convert one by one

Comment: If you convert all faces then all faces will simply flip, meaning that certain faces that were facing the right way, will also convert. So select faces you want to flip with 'Ctrl' and flip them.